# Find a word in a string that starts with "PID" and return the word (in R)

Tags: regex, r

I need to search for a large amount of strings to find a "word" that starts with PID. PID is an ID tag, and they're all numbered (PID1, PID23, etc.)

Example of a string to search through:
PID442 WALKS TO TOWN

I need to return the specific ID so the output is "PID442." I was trying to do this in R.

Comment: does every string contain a PID? can it contain more than one? what should your output look like under these possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(str, "\\bPID\\d+\\b", c, perl = TRUE, simplify = TRUE)
[1] "PID442" "PID1"
```

Comment: I tried this on all of my data, and it looks like it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yet another method, which (I hope) is a little simpler:

```
> str <- 'PID442 WALKS TO TOWN'
> regmatches(str, regexpr('\\<PID\\w*\\>', str))
[1] "PID442"
```

`regexpr` gets the position in `str` of the first match. (If you are looking for multiple matches in a string, as in some of the other answers, just replace `regexpr` with `gregexpr`.) `regmatches` returns the string corresponding to the match.

In the regular expression:
`\\<` and `\\>` mark the beginning and end of words.
`\\w` matches a 'word' character, so `\\w*` matches zero or more word characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
str <- c("PID442 WALKS TO TOWN", "I AM PID1")
gsub(".*\\b(PID\\d+)\\b.*", "\\1", str)
#[1] "PID442" "PID1"
```

`\\b` is a word boundary which matches at the start or the end of a word

`\\d+` corresponds to a positive amount of digits

`.*` is a nonnegative amount of anything

`\\1` replaces every element of `str` with the `PID\\d+`, i.e. the part of regular expression that is inside the first parentheses

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at regular expressions last night but haven't used them before.

Comment: @user2709239, no problem, let me know if you still find something unclear in my solution. And don't forget that you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the tick mark on the left.

Comment: After using it on the data, it seems to run into problems by accepting any word with a capital P, I, or D. I couldn't fix that.

Comment: @user2709239, yes, actually it is not just P, I or D. It accepts full string in case there is no PID at all since you did not mention that it is possible and what output you want in that case (NA, NULL in a list or something else).